# Access all user data in AzureBotStorage

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-table-storage, azure-bot-service

I've created a chatbot using the Bot Builder SDK for Node.js. As this will be hosted on Azure, I'm using AzureBotStorage (`botbuilder-azure` module) in the hosted environment, and MemoryBotStorage (`botbuilder` module) in dev.

The initialization is something like:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var azure = require('botbuilder-azure');

var stateStorage = {};

if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT != "DEV") {
    var azureTableClient = new azure.AzureTableClient(process.env.TABLE_NAME, process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME, process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY);
    stateStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, azureTableClient);
} else {
    stateStorage = new builder.MemoryBotStorage();
}
```

This works great in general - I've confirmed (using the Storage Explorer tool) that the user conversation data's getting stored in both the local and hosted environments.

The problem is, I'm having trouble *accessing* said storage data within the app (I'm trying to iterate through all users as a part of a separate function).

Something like this:

```
for (userId in stateStorage.userStore)
```

works great for accessing the local environment storage (`builder.MemoryBotStorage()`), but does not work at all for the hosted environment storage (`azure.AzureBotStorage()`). In fact, I just can't find a way to access/query the AzureBotStorage data, period.

Does anyone have experience with accessing AzureBotStorage data, and if so, how would you suggest iterating through all users?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/search?q=exportBotStateData

Comment: What do you want the `all users`? users in your server's session, or the all users in a particular channel?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT all the users from a particular channel. Basically, I've got an hourly scheduled cron job, which (each time it runs) will iterate through the userData table, check all user's preferences, and for the ones that match certain conditions, reach out to them with a proactive message.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to access the table using `buildTableService().queryEntities()`, like so:

```
azureTableClient.buildTableService().queryEntities(process.env.TABLE_NAME, null, null, function (error, result, response) {
    for (var i=0; i<result.entries.length; i++) {
        \\ do stuff with result.entries[i]
    }
});
```

However, this method isn't particularly clean or efficient, so I'm leaving the question unanswered for now, in case anyone has a better approach.